# How to remove all scripts in page, even those attached to events and timers?

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with JavaScript & I can't seem to understand simple behavior. What I want to do, is to disable absolutely any JS that was before the following code snippet:

```
void (function(){
    (function prepare(name){ 
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(name);
        for(var i = elements.length; i--;)
            elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
        return prepare;
    }('script'));
}());
```

**NOTE Marcel Korpel**: indenting inserted for readability, but you should paste this as one line-of-code in the address bar.

The following code theoretically should disabled all the JS on the page, right? To test it, you can execute it via `javascript: [..]` when the page is fully loaded. FireBug HTML will show that all scripts are removed. However, there were things in code like `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, binding specific actions, on click events, etc. and they still work even after the code is executed.

Is there a way to completely remove all of this after the script is executed?

Comment: All preceding scripts are executed before your script remove their `<script/>` tags. Tags removing doesn't unload executed code or remove event listeners defined by executed code. You can prevent event bubbling by setup your own event listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, timeouts (as in `setTimeout`) and intervals (`setInterval`) are opaque. This means there is no way to cancel running timeout/interval w/o knowing its handle. Same is for event listeners, DOM object's event sink is not available, so no way to `removeEventListener` without knowledge how `addEventListener` was called.

The only way i can figure out is user javascript in Opera, where you can hook functions listed above and keep track of timeouts/intervals/listeners.

Comment: You can cancel all the timeouts without identifiers, but it is a brute.Every timeout or interval returns a larger integer than any previous existing timer, and the integer is the value passed when you call clearTimeout(reference). You can capture the next integer by creating a dummy timeout and loop clearTimeout (integer--) to zero. The thing that makes it a brute is that some browsers begin the series with an arbrtrarily large integer.

Comment: @kennebec, yes, it is exploitable, however sequence not guaranteed, see formal spec: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout

Answer (score 1):

After the script evaluation, you can't remove JavaScript that way. If you know the object needed to delete, you can use the brute-force way:

```
for (var key in window) {
    window[key] = undefined;
}
```

but it doesn't remove events.

Events are complicated, depends on what kind of event system used...
The old DOM events can be removed with recursive iteration on DOM and removing any kind of event attribute on the DOM elements.

Modern event system can be disabled a bit tricky:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +'';
```

But this solution have some possible memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the answers an comments and have come up with this function...

```
function KILL(){
 document.body.style='';
 document.body.innerHTML = 'KILLED';

 a=setTimeout(function(){},1)
 for (var i = a; i >= 0; i--) {
  clearTimeout(i);
  clearInterval(i);
 }

 for (var key in window) {
  if(key != 'location' && key != 'KILL'){
     window[key] = undefined;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I think it covers the suggestions and comments. Not sure how it affects existing styles from loaded stylesheets, and also scripts that are loading.

Comment: I think outerHTML might be a better way to clear the body tag as it will clear any attributes in the tag `document.body.outerHTML = '<body>KILLED</body>';`